# Writing Async requests in python

Tags: python-3.x, api, asynchronous, python-requests

I am planning of writing async requests in python 3. I came across 2 packages urlib and requests. I am confused about using which of the following package which will give me more performance and won't consume many resources.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It doesn't really fit to my answer, so here it goes: I hope by requests you mean you want to write a physical request to an API asynchronously, not rewrite requests library in async, because, well... That's already a thing: https://github.com/jsandovalc/aiorequests :) No need to reinvent the wheel when people already did a billion times, aiohttp is still better.

Comment: I want to know if both libraries support Async Method.

Comment: Neither urllib nor requests support non-blocking connection, the best you can do with them is use threading.

Comment: Which library supports the nonblocking connection in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might look like an opinion to everyone, but trust me, it's not:

If you have to ask, you'll never know, that being said, just use [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question and you might've got your answer as well but this is my script in case someone is still looking for the solution.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time

async def send_request(session, url, data, i):
    start_time = time.time()
    async with session.post(url, data=data) as response:
        end_time = time.time()

        if response.status == 200:
            print(f"Request {i+1} successful! Execution time: {end_time - start_time} seconds")
        else:
            print(f"Request {i+1} failed with status code: {response.status}")

async def send_multiple_requests(url, n):
    data = {
        'key1': 'value1' #replace with your actual request body
    }

    total_start_time = time.time()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for i in range(n):
            task = asyncio.create_task(send_request(session, url, data, i))
            tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    total_end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Total time to run {n} requests: {total_end_time - total_start_time} seconds\n")

url = 'https://example.com/abc'  # Replace with your actual URL
n = 4  # Number of async requests
asyncio.run(send_multiple_requests(url, n))
```